# PHP Tickbox caching data

Tags: php, content-management-system, hybrid-mobile-app

I am currently developing a Hybrid App CMS and one of the elements within my CMS is the use of tickboxes when selecting use cases. (This only happens in chrome) I click on several tickboxes to select a bunch of use cases and then when I go off onto another page or even filter a search result and the unfilter the search result the ticks that I have selected are not there anymore. I want the data to be cached so that the cases I have selected stay saved on the page. I am coding the whole of the CMS in PHP.

This is a piece of code that relates to the tick boxes

// Output each event (unless filtered) and track rows

```
  $row_count = 0;

  foreach( $this->usecases as $usecase ) {
    if ( $this->apply_filters($usecase) ) {

      $row_count += 1;

      if ( $usecase["USECASE_ACTIVE"] ) {

        $active_class    = " class='event-active'";
        $active_checkbox = <<<EOF
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

EOF;

```
      } else {

        $active_class    = "";
        $active_checkbox = sprintf( $checkbox_template, $usecase["USECASE_ID"] );

      }

      echo sprintf(
        $row_template,
        $active_class, $active_checkbox,
        $usecase["USECASE_NAME"], $usecase["USECASE_CATEGORIES"], $usecase["USECASE_ID"]
      );

    }
  }
```

Comment: maybe use session or cookie to cache it

Comment: Would you know how to implment this into PHP?

Comment: if you post some detail codes, i maybe able to help

Comment: I have added code from the CMS in the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan. Try something along the lines of this...

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache(); //use APC as the driver
$fruits = $cache->fetch('fruits'); //fetch the data from the cache

if($fruits == null){
  $fruits = array('apple', 'orange', 'grapes', 'coconut', 'papaya');
  $cache->save('fruits', $fruits); //save data into the cache
}

//do something with $fruits
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, just online. No really understand your codes, but expanding my ideas base on my understanding of your question. Please check below the example for test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['action'])&&$_POST['action']=='checkBox')
{
    $_SESSION['number']=$_POST['checkedVal'];
    exit;
}
?>
<form>
<fieldset>
    <?php
        $vals=['1','2','3'];
        foreach($vals as $val)
        {
            $checked="";

            if(isset($_SESSION['number'])&&in_array($val,$_SESSION['number']))
            {
                $checked="checked";
            }
            echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"number[]\" value=\"$val\" $checked />$val";
        }
    ?>
</fieldset>
</form>
<a href="test.php">Go another page</a>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("input[name='number[]']").change(function() {
        var checked=new Array();
        $.each($("input[name='number[]']:checked"), function() {
            checked.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.post("test.php", { action: "checkBox", checkedVal: checked } );
    });
});
</script>
```